# JSON Jersey JAXB

Tags: java, json, curl, jaxb

I cant seem to post JSON to my webservice but XML works fine:

```
     @POST
 @Consumes({"application/xml","application/json"})
 public  void addOrder(JAXBElement<OrderBean>  order) {
     System.out.println("COOL");
 }



curl -v -X POST --data-binary "<orderBean><customer>test</customer></orderBean>" -H"Content-Type: application/xml"  http://localhost:8080/webapp/rest/order


curl -v -X POST --data-binary "{"orderBean":{"customer":"test"}}" -H"Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/webapp/rest/order
```

I get the following error with JSON:

```
java.lang.Error: Error: could not match input
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonLexer.zzScanError(JsonLexer.java:491)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think maybe you just need to escape the `"`'s on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

When your `OrderBean` is properly annotated with any `@XmlXXX`, you don't have to wrap it with `JAXBElement<>`

```
@POST
@Consumes(...)
public void addOrder(final OrderBean order) {
}
```

And you should send exactly the same JSON string Jersey can parse.

That means you should send exactly the same structure of JSON string that the Jersey prints

Please see

http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#d4e949

and

[Print Jersey JSON in Unit Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593543/print-jersey-json-in-unit-testing)