# Print Jersey JSON in Unit Testing

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey

Is there any plain way

- to print a JAXB annotated instance
- in JSON format (as exactly jersey will print in AS)
- while running unit testing
- without any embedded server launched?

I can run and see in XML with JAXBContext, Marshaller, and so on.

Is there any example for JSON?

---

I found it. It's similar to JAXB.

With [Jersey API](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/index.html)

```java
final JSONJAXBContext context = new JSONJAXBContext(...);

final JSONMarshaller marshaller = context.createJSONMarshaller();
marshaller.marshallToJSON(...);

final JSONUnmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createJSONUnmarshaller();
final T unmarshalled = unmarshaller.unmarshalJAXBElementFromJSON(
        ..., T.class).getValue();
```

---

for Maven

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible:

```
...
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
marshaller.marshallToJSON(objectToMarshall, writer)
logger.debug(writer.toString());
...
```

You can use an `StringWriter` to take the `String` representation of the marshalled JSON output.